# How was Dumbledore's portrait put up so quickly?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince*, when Harry goes into the headmaster's/headmistresse's study with McGonagall, Dumbledore's portrait is already on the wall, how was it painted so quickly? Did someone paint it really fast or is it part of the magic of Hogwarts?

Comment: It was done using magic

Comment: Who did it? everyone was still mourning him

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the ["Howarts Portraits"](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-portraits) article by JK Rowling on Pottermore, the headmaster portraits are actually painted before the headmaster dies:

> Traditionally, a headmaster or headmistress is painted before their
>   death. Once the portrait is completed, the headmaster or headmistress
>   in question keeps it under lock and key, regularly visiting it in its
>   cupboard (if so desired) to teach it to act and behave exactly like
>   themselves, and imparting all kinds of useful memories and pieces of
>   knowledge that may then be shared through the centuries with their
>   successors in office.

Thus, when Dumbledore died all they had to do was take the portrait out of its cupboard and hang it on the wall, which should only take a matter of seconds.

Comment: I dunno man, it takes me way longer to hang pictures on walls, ask my wife!

Comment: Thanks that clears it up.

Comment: @Möoz maybe, but then, how good a wizard are you?

Comment: @M'vy Hmm, about 7.